# Dynamic loading of Haskell abstract syntax expression

Tags: haskell, dynamic-loading, ghc-api

Can we use GHC API or something else to load not text source modules, but AST expressions, similar to [haskell-src-exts `Exp` type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.11.1/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Exp)? This way we could save time for code generation and parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the GHC API exposes an AST interface (could be wrong though), but Template Haskell does.  If you build expressions using the `Language.Haskell.TH` `Exp` structure, you can create functions/declarations and make use of them by the `$(someTHFunction)` syntax.

A fairly major caveat is that TH only runs at compile time, so you would need to pre-generate everything.  If you want to use TH at run-time, I think you'd need to pretty-print the template haskell AST, then use the GHC API on the resulting string.

Comment: Also I can generate Template Haskell source code. This can be considered as compromise between generating AST expressions and generating Haskell text source.