# How to convert an expression in Haskell to a Tree structure to get information in the expression?

Tags: regex, haskell, functional-programming

is there a way to convert an expression in **Haskell** language to a Tree like format and extract information from each node. Or Generate all possible trees for a given expression ?
Ex: **add 5 3** 
This is tree where, 3 and 5 are leaf nodes and "**add**" as the root. So what I need is to get decompose the above expression so that I can do further analysis on the expression. 
eg: * *to know what are the values that I'm going to "add".*
    * *to know what is the operation that I'm performing over the given numbers (here "add", also it could be "subtraction", "multiplication" etc.*)
    Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic loading of Haskell abstract syntax expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881263/dynamic-loading-of-haskell-abstract-syntax-expression). In general, questions under the [ghc-api] and [template-haskell] tags might prove useful.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Template Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell):

```
Language.Haskell.TH> runQ [e|3 + 5|]
InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 3))) (VarE GHC.Num.+) (Just (LitE (IntegerL 5)))
```

Or [`haskell-src-exts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts):

```
Language.Haskell.Exts> parse "3 + 5" :: ParseResult Exp
ParseOk (InfixApp (Lit (Int 3)) (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "+"))) (Lit (Int 5)))
```